# How can I take immediate payment plus recurring via PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using Express Checkout, and I would like to set up a scenario as follows:

- $10 is charged right now
- A monthly payment of $15 is set up

So if today is day 0, on day 0 they'd be billed $10, on day 1, they'd be billed $15, and then on day 61 they'd be billed $15 again (and so on).

I'm doing this using the `trialamt`, `trialtotalbillingcycles`, `trialbillingperiod` and `trialbillingfrequency` parameters. This sets up a payments profile like in this screenshot:

[image: Example screenshot of no payments taken out]

As you can see, this was set up on May 6th. No money has been taken out, not even the initial amount there, and it says that the next payment due is May 6th, and the profile start date was then too. Is there some gigantic delay on the sandbox? It's been 3 days now.

Alternatively is there another way to do this? I could make a standard Express Checkout payment for the today amount and then use the `profilestartdate` to start it tomorrow. However, I believe that if you set a future date using `profilestartdate`, the profile is marked as 'suspended' and you nor the customer can cancel it until it's activated.

Comment: Are you still having an issue?  There was a delay in the PayPal Sandbox but it should be resolved now.  If you have delays still it would most likely be to the credit card number being used.  If that is the case generating some new test card numbers using step 4 here should help: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1413&expand=true&locale=en_US

Comment: This does seem to be resolved now, yes. This delay is the second or third time I've come across it over a period of several weeks, and it seems to get resolved and then come back again. Has it been fully resolved now would you say? Thanks for the help!

Comment: A more complete solution is still in the works. However, if you use new test card numbers this should limit future impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does appear to be a delay, especially on the sandbox, of anything up to several days. This makes testing difficult sometimes. An alternative might be to use both a one-off Express Checkout payment *instead of* using the `initamt` field, since you can get the user to confirm both the subscription and payment for an item at the same time.